# Create Windows Installer MSI for adding an AddIn for Power Point

Tags: windows-installer

I have a Dotnet solution which adds an AddIn extension to MSPowerPoint which is like a tab and it adds some powerpoint template. Now I want it to push in all the laptops which requires an MSI to be generated and pushed to all machines which can install it. Suggest me the way we can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, free and paid, it all depends on the time you have on your hands.

- free [VS solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019)
- paid - Advanced Installer - [demo video](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/office-addin-deployment.html)

*Disclaimer: I work on the Advanced Installer team*